# Mocking an action with metaClass in Grails

Tags: grails, service, mocking, action

I'm trying to mock the action **overview** of a Controller, but it isn't working.

I tried this ways:

```
MyController.metaClass.overview = { ->
        println "MOCKED OVERVIEW"
        render(view:"overview", model)
    }

MyController.metaClass.demand.overview = { ->
        println "MOCKED OVERVIEW"
        render(view:"overview", model)
    }

MyController.metaClass.static.overview = { ->
        println "MOCKED OVERVIEW"
        render(view:"overview", model)
    }
```

All this didn't work.

But i used .metaClass to mock some services, and it worked.

Why with this action isn't working ?

The println statment is never showed.

Comment: why are you doing this?  Why not do what it says at http://www.grails.org/Testing+Controllers?  Im just curious...

Comment: I was trying to mock de action because mocking the services wasn't doing what i was expecting.

But now i see that its an error. I just mocked the services that the action use and no more.

The action should really act correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action needs to be there during Grails' bootstrap - in order to generate URLs and all the Spring beans. You can't override it (that easy) after application is initialized.

Anyway, you souldn't need to - actions should be simple. Any testable logic should be testable on its own.